# Sum array values into a matrix in python in a quick way

Tags: python, arrays, optimization, matrix, sum

I have two arrays with indices (row and column) and one array with values. What I would like to do is to add the values from the array, to the values in a corresponding matrix, using the arrays with row and column indices. I also need to keep track of how many times I have added a value into a certain place.

This is no problem using a for loop. However in my case this will take many hours to do.
So is there a faster way to do what the code below does?

```
number = np.zeros([2,2])
amount = np.zeros([2,2])
row = np.array([1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0])
col = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1])
values = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
for i in range(len(row)):
    r = row[i]
    c = col[i]
    v = values[i]
    amount[r, c] = amount[r, c] + v
    number[r, c] = number[r, c] + 1
```

The results will in this example look like

```
amount = array([[  4.,  25.],
                [ 11.,  15.]])
```

and

```
number = array([[ 1.,  3.],
                [ 2.,  4.]])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've seen, numpy isn't great for this type of problem, at least not in my estimation. This is something that I might write in cython or C and glue together with the rest of my python code.

A straightforward iterative solution will take time linear in the size of `values`. The best solution I can think of with numpy requires a sort, so it takes `O(n log n)`. It will still be faster than the iterative solution in pure Python for small input, but asymptotically it should actually be worse.

In any case, here's the code:

```
def numpy_assign(values, row, col):
    # arrange the values so that entries are contiguous
    ix = np.ravel_multi_index((row, col), (2,2))
    sort_ix = np.argsort(ix)

    ix = ix[sort_ix]
    values = values[sort_ix]

    # now we need to construct the funny index argument 
    # to the `reduceat` ufunc method
    reduce_ix = np.where(np.diff(ix))[0] + 1
    reduce_ix = np.insert(reduce_ix, 0, 0)

    # reduce the amounts
    amount = np.add.reduceat(values, reduce_ix).reshape(2,2)

    # and count the number of times we've done so
    _, counts = np.unique(ix, return_counts=True)
    counts = counts.reshape(2,2)

    return amount, counts
```

Now, if you have [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/) in your python distribution (I'm just using the standard installation that comes with the academic license of the Anaconda distribution), then we can actually do quite a bit better without much extra work:

```
import numba

@numba.autojit
def inner_loop(row, col, values, number, amount):
    for i in range(len(row)):
        r = row[i]
        c = col[i]
        v = values[i]
        amount[r, c] += v
        number[r, c] += 1

def numba_assign(row, col, values):
    number = np.zeros([2,2], np.float)
    amount = np.zeros([2,2], np.float)
    inner_loop(row, col, values, number, amount)
    return amount, number
```

How much faster is this? On a random input of 1e6 entries, we get the times:

```
>>> %timeit loop_assign(row, col, values)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.35 s per loop

>>> %timeit numpy_assign(row, col, values)
10 loops, best of 3: 81 ms per loop

>>> %timeit numba_assign(row, col, values)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.33 ms per loop
```

`loop_assign` is your original code. Note that `numba_assign` not only runs much faster than the numpy solution, but it doesn't require a sort, so it has linear asymptotic complexity, meaning that it scales better.

Comment: I actually tried using cython as well (for the original code with for loops) but it was not a big time different between the regular python and cython. However I am new to cython so maybe it can be optimized somehow. So far using numpy is the fastest way that I have tried, however it requires numpy 1.9 or higher to be able to use the return_counts option.

Comment: I've edited in a new solution using `numba`. I think it will give you close to optimal performance without changing your code much at all.